# TypeScript 5 method decorator is not working in Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

Here I have simple TypeScript 5 decorator which logs method response (some functions are hidden to not overcomplicate stuff here):

```
export const LogResponse = <Args extends any[] = any[]>(
    options: LogResponseOptions = defaultLogResponseOptions
) => {
    return (
        originalMethod: (this: any, ...args: Args) => any,
        context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<any, (this: any, ...args: Args) => any>
    ) => {
        // ... 

        return function (this: any, ...args: Args) {
            try {
                const pending = originalMethod.call(this, ...args);
                if (pending instanceof Promise) return handlePromise(pending);
                return logResponseAndReturn(pending, options.level!);
            } catch (error) {
                if (error instanceof Error) logInformation(LogLevel.error, error.message);
                throw error;
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Below is example of simple application which works as expected:

```
(async () => {
    class Test {
        @LogResponse()
        public test() {
            return 'test1';
        }
    }

    const test = new Test();
    test.test();
})();
```

[image]

I tried covering `LogDecorator` with unit tests (using Jest). Here it is:

```
describe(LogResponse.name, () => {
    const mockedResponse = 'mocked response';

    class MockClass {
        @LogResponse()
        public mockMethod() {
            return mockedResponse;
        }
    }
    
    describe('Successful log', () => {
        const mockClass = new MockClass();

        it('Should log response', async () => {
            const spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
            const response = mockClass.mockMethod();
            expect(response).toEqual(mockedResponse);
            expect(spy).toBeCalledWith(`[LOG] mockMethod: ${mockedResponse}`);
        });
    });
});
```

This is where my test fails:
[image]

After debugging unit tests, I found out that arguments `originalMethod` and `context` are invalid (and very unexpected. `originalMethod` must be function and `context` must be an object).
[image]

I think that's the reason why method cannot be overridden and response in not logged during the tests. But I couldn't find the root cause yet.